# Are these subgraphs of equal size?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a (finite) connected graph.

Let $H_1,\ldots, H_n$ be distinct subgraphs of $G$ of the same order (=number of vertices).

Suppose that there exists $k$ such that every edge of $G$ belongs to precisely $k$ of the $H_i$.

Must all of the $H_i$ be of the same size (=number of edges)?

This fails if $G$ is not connected (as the disjoint union of path and cycle shows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ have edges 12, 23, 13, 14, and 45; let $H_1$ have edges 12, 23, and 13, while $H_2$ has edges 14, and 45.

$H_1$ has 3 vertices (1, 2, 3), so does $H_2$ (1, 4, 5).

Every edge of $G$ belongs to precisely one of the $H_i$.

But $H_1$ has 3 edges, while $H_2$ has 2.